# OpwenWrt - reading byte from SPI with Python

Tags: python, gpio, spi, openwrt

I want to read bytes from the spi bus.
Writing a byte is simple by just using

```
file = open("/dev/spidev1.0", 'wb')
file.write('#')
```

I tried using the read(1) command, but this makes the spi clock way longer than just for one byte.

Example:

```
file = open("/dev/spidev1.0", 'rb')
file.read(1)
```

Does anyone have a clue why it just doenst clock 8 times when I try to read one byte?

(I am using a Carambola2 by the way and the spi over gpio)

Comment: Could you give a little more details about your hardware and its configuration? E.g. https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?294792-What-s-the-different-between-GPIO-port-and-SPI suggests that a GPIO pin can be configured as either input or output, not both; and an SPI device can be either a master or slave.

Comment: Its configured as master. Actually i just used the command:
insmod spi-gpio-custom bus0=$SPI_DEVICE_NUMBER,$SPI_SCLK,$SPI_MOSI,$SPI_MISO,$SPI_MODE,$SPI_HZ

Comment: Also, what does "makes the spi clock way longer than just for one byte" mean? If that means a longer delay before `read` returns, maybe the program is just waiting for any data to arrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem on my own.
You have to use the os library

Example:

```
import os

file = os.open('filename', os.O_RDWR)

#Write byte 0x1 to SPI Bus
os.write(file, chr(0x1))
#Read one byte from SPI Bus
print(str(ord(os.read(file, 1))))
```